# How to implement Google Maps API into NSB AppStudio

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Looking for some insight on how to add a Google Map into my NSB AppStudio project.

**NOTE**: I am required to code it myself instead of using the "Google Map" control that AppStudio provides.

I am decent with HTML and better with JavaScript, but I'm finding it really difficult to code in AppStudio.

**My goal is to have the map with this information information:**

```
//Name, Latitude, Longitude
center = ["Heider College of Business", 41.265345335859166, -95.9433146928534]
markers = [["Cafe Postale", 41.250562428008244, -95.933675618658],["Myrtle and Cypress", 41.264175225229884, -95.96128391887339]]
```

**My the code for my form is currently:**

```
function initMap() {
const myLatLng = { lat: 41.265345335859166, lng: -95.9433146928534};
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
zoom: 4,
center: myLatLng,
});

new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatLng,
map,
title: "Hello World!",
});
}

//I deleted my API key where MY_API_KEY is just for this post :)
let src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap"

frmMap.onshow=function(){
window.initMap = initMap;
}
```

Nothing is displaying on my form. Not sure what to do.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Is the `onshow` ever called? What do you do with the `src` variable? Are you not supposed to create a `<script>` with that `src` variable as the `<script src="">`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Yes the code works. I'm just not sure how to properly use my code from AppStudio's controls. The onshow is called automatically when the page is loaded. src imports the google maps API, so that I may create the google.maps object in initMap.

Comment: That, somehow, didn't clarify anything.